# Concavity of a function implicitly defined by a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-curves, convexity, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider the following system of $n$ equations:

\begin{equation}f_j^2 = x_j^2\sum_{i=1}^n A_{ij} f_i 
\tag{$\star$}
\end{equation}

where $A_{ij}\geq 0$ are known constants and where $x_j>0$ for all $j$. I am interested in the concavity properties (log-concavity or quasi-concavity) of $f_j$ as a function of the vector $x$. In general, $f_j$ is not concave.

> Under what conditions on the $A_{ij}$'s is $f_j$ a log-concave or
>   quasi-concave function of the vector $x$?

A few observations:

1. The system has a trivial solution at $f=0$. Taking the square root on both sides of the equation, we can use Theorem 3 in this [note](http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~jkennan/research/FixedPoint21.pdf) to find that there is a unique non-trivial positive solution $f$ for a given $x$.
2. The same note shows that we can reach this solution by iterating on the mapping. Therefore, if we start with log-concave (for instance) functions and keep iterating we should converge to a log-concave solution if the mapping preserves log-concavity. Sadly, summation does not preserve log-concavity (or quasi-concavity).
3. By iterating on the mapping we get the following nested radicals structure
   $$f_j=x_j\sqrt{\sum_lA_{lj}x_l\sqrt{\sum_iA_{il}x_i\sqrt{\dots}}}$$
4. $f$ is homogeneous of degree 2 in $x$. There are some results about the concavity of homogenous polynomial (see for instance the [top of page 127](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/serre/DPF/exobis.pdf)) but again they do not apply directly here. Maybe another version of these results would?
5. In simple cases in which we can solve the problem by hand, I find log-concave solutions. For instance, with $A_{ij}=1$ if $i=j$ and 0 otherwise we get $f_j=x_j^2$ which is log-concave. I am hoping that this is a general property of the solution.

Motivation:

- I am interested in the optimization problem
  $$
  \max_{0\leq x_j\leq 1,\,\forall j} \log\left(\sum_{j=1}^n f_j(x)\right)+\log\left(L-\sum_{j=1}^n x_j\right)
  $$
  where $f_j$ satisfies equation $\star$ above and where $L>n$.
- Understanding the concavity of $f_j$ is a step in understanding the concavity of the objective function.
- It is possible to replace the equality in $\star$ by $\leq$ and consider an optimization problem with respect to both $f$ and $x$ with the modified equation $\star$ as a constraint.
- One restriction that would natural in the context of my problem would be to set $A_{ii}=0$ for all $i$.

Please feel free to assume additional assumptions on the problem if needed.

Comment: What's the question in your post ?

Comment: @dohmatob Under what conditions on the $A_{ij}$'s is $f_j$ a log-concave or quasi-concave function of the vector $x$. I've edited the question for clarity.

Comment: Cute question but I'm curious if you have tried the "brain-free" approach (i.e., numerical simulations) already, and, if you have, what it indicated.

Comment: The system $f^2=x^2(2f+1g), g^2=y^2(0f+1g)$ has solution $f=x(x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$, which is not quasi-concave near the $x$-axis, so down the drain goes the hope that the quasi-concavity property is universal. At this point you'd rather tell what you really need if you want the further discussion to be reasonably productive...

Comment: Thanks @fedja. I suspected that the result does not hold for all $A_{ij}$. I'd like to find conditions on these coefficients such that it does. I have added a motivation to the post.

Comment: Does $0\le x\le 1$ mean $0\le x_j\le 1$ for all $j$ or something else?

Comment: Yes for all $j$. I have clarified the question.

Comment: Also what do you want exactly: a reasonably fast algorithm for finding the true maximum, an explicit formula approximating the maximum, or something else altogether?

Comment: @fedja I would like to show that the objective function is quasiconcave so that the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions are necessary and sufficient.

Comment: Well, we have already figured out that it isn't in general, so that won't work. Moreover, even in some cases when the individual $f_j$ are good (say, $A=I$), the compound expression you have may be bad. This leaves very little chance for showing anything like what you've requested unless your $A$ is some very special matrix. If so, what is it?

Comment: @fedja I don't have any a priori restrictions on $A$. I'm interested in the set of $A$ for which this works. One restriction that would be natural however is $A_{ii}=0$ for all $i$. Thanks for your help by the way.